# How to get the value of a const with ML code in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I wrote a definition in my theory, say:

**definition mycmd :: string where
"mycmd == ''external_executable''"**

Then I need to use the value of **mycmd**, which is **"external_executable"**, in a ML code block as the argument of **Isabelle_System.bash_output**, but I don't know how to obtain the value of **mycmd**. Is there any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To statically evaluate an Isabelle/HOL term in Isabelle/ML, you normally use the @{code} antiquotation. In your example, this reads as `ML {* @{code mycmd} *}`. Isabelle will insert the necessary code to evaluate `mycmd` at compile time and use that value. The only difficulty is that the HOL type `string` does not serialise to the ML type `string`. Therefore, you should use the type `String.literal` in the HOL term and use that.

Here's your example for Isabelle2014:

```
definition mycmd :: String.literal where "mycmd == STR ''external_executable''"
ML {* Isabelle_System.bash_output @{code mycmd} *}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, even though I don't really understand what you want to do:

```
ML {*  Thm.concl_of @{thm mycmd_def}
  |> Term.dest_comb |> snd
  |> HOLogic.dest_string *}
```

and for a more robust version (depending on the definition style, with "=" or "=="):

```
ML {* Thm.concl_of @{thm mycmd_def}
  |> (fn x => if fst (dest_Const (fst (strip_comb x))) = @{const_name "Trueprop"} 
    then snd (dest_comb x) else x)
  |> dest_comb |> snd
  |> HOLogic.dest_string *}
```